# Python svglib SVG to PNG RenderScale error

Tags: python, svg, png

I'm trying to use the Python library svglib (I'm using Python3.8) to render an SVG to a PNG and I'm just following the example on the github page https://github.com/deeplook/svglib with this

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

imageLoc = getDir() + "/csvs/image.csv"
image = svg2rlg(imageLoc)

pngLoc = getDir() + "pngs/image.png"
renderPM.drawToFile(image, pngLoc, fmt="PNG", dpi=1024)
```

But I'm getting an error on the call to `renderPM`

```
'str' object has no attribute 'renderScale'
```

Is this something that is missing from the svg itself? I'm only using a very basic svg

```
<svg id="svgTest" viewBox="0 0 600 400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect id="background" fill="#EEEEEE" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="400"></rect>
<text class="textTemplate text1" fill="#666666" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="0" x="115" y="35" style="font-family:Monospace;font-size:25px;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Filepath should be wrong in imageLoc. `print(image)`  will give you None. or may be the svg is loaded as a string.

Comment: The svg is loaded as a string but how do I change that?